# Set Posting Date based on max delivery date from selected product receipt of Purchase Order in axapta 2012 r2

Tags: axapta, x++

I am newbie in Microsoft Dynamics Axapta 2012 R2 and x++ programming.
I have created Purchase Order transaction and it's status has been received. Please refer to this screenshot below.

[image]

And then I want to create invoice for this purchase order, so I click on Invoice button like the following screenshot.

[image]

After that I click on Match Product Receipt button to show the form for select which product receipt that I need to process for invoicing. Please refer the following screenshot.

[image]

And then, I choose some product receipt for invoicing, please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

Based on screenshot above I choose 4 product receipts, and in every product receipt has the delivery date. My goal is I want to pass max value from these delivery date of selected product receipt, and in this case I need delivery date = '4/17/2017' will be passed to Posting Date field of Vendor Invoice Form based on OK button. And then Posting Date will be shown like the following screenshot.

[image]

Does anyone know how to provide it ? many appreciate for everyone who can help me.. :)

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far? If you are new to Dynamics AX development, you may want to start with an easier requirement or get some additional training. This requirement needs some understanding of the FormLetter framework that powers all the posting processes and to give you that understanding is too broad a topic for a Stack Overflow question.